Intuitive meaning of 'Affine' in algebraic geometry
The word 'affine' is a word that frequently appears in various subjects of algebra, whether linear algebra or algebraic geometry. For example, in linear algebra, there is something called an affine transformation.

Let $X$ be an affine space over a field $k$, and $V$ be its associated vector space. An affine transformation is a bijection $f$ from $X$ onto itself that is an affine map this means that a linear map $g$ from $V$ to $V$ is well defined by the equation $g(y-x)=f(y)-f(x)$ here, as usual, the subtraction of two points denotes the free vector from the second point to the first one, and 'well-defined' means that $y-x=y'-x'$ implies that $f(y)-f(x)=f(y')-f(x')$

And as an example in algebraic geometry, let's write a spectrum of a ring.

Given the space ${\displaystyle X=\operatorname {Spec} (R)}$ with the Zariski topology, the structure sheaf ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {O}}_{X}}$ is defined on the distinguished open subsets ${\displaystyle D_{f}}$ by setting ${\displaystyle \Gamma (D_{f},{\mathcal {O}}_{X})=R_{f},}$ the localization of $R$ by the powers of $f$. It can be shown that this defines a B-sheaf and therefore that it defines a sheaf. In more detail, the distinguished open subsets are a basis of the Zariski topology, so for an arbitrary open set $U$, written as the union of ${\textstyle U=\bigcup _{i\in I}D_{f_{i}}}$, we set ${\textstyle \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X})=\varprojlim _{i\in I}R_{f_{i}},}$ where ${\displaystyle \varprojlim }$ denotes the limit with respect to the natural ring homomorphisms ${\displaystyle R_{f}\to R_{fg}.}$ One may check that this presheaf is a sheaf, so ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Spec} (R)}$ is a ringed space. Any ringed space isomorphic to one of this form is called an affine scheme. General schemes are obtained by gluing affine schemes together.

Like above, usual thinking about affine means that distort the original space (rotate it, stretch it, shrink it). However, the meaning of affine in algebraic geometry seems to be slightly different. How should we interpret the intuitive meaning of affine in algebraic geometry?

Think first of classical affine varieties. You can represent these as schemes using a general construction that we now term "affine" scheme. A super general affine scheme over some general ring doesn't have much in the way of intuitive, visual 'affine' geometry, but the name sticks because it's the same construction we use for classical affine schemes

@FShrike Hello, thank you very much for your comment. So, are you saying that algebraic geometry also has the same property (rotate it, stretch it, shrink it) as I wrote about in the linear algebra example earlier?

No I’m not saying anything like that. Though the general linear and affine groups do act on some affine and projective schemes. I’m just saying there’s history. The use of “affine” in algebraic geometry by far predates the modern conception of “affine scheme”.

@FShrike Thank you for your comment! I understood your comment!

In algebraic geometry, affine schemes/varieties are those which are perfectly described by their ring of functions. The path from the "affine space" to the "affine variety" is that affine varieties are those that admit a closed immersion in to affine space (in the sense of a vector space over a field where we forget the origin), and then one notices that an affine variety is perfectly described by its ring of functions, and then one calls schemes which also satisfy that property affine schemes.

hello. Thank you very much for your answer. However, what I would like to know in more detail is the intuitive feeling of summarizing the properties of affine in algebraic geometry as I described as (rotate it, stretch it, shrink it).

@user1274233 Well, you're out of luck, because that's not what it means, and those concepts aren't really related to the concept of affine in algebraic geometry except through this linkage.

Okay, I understood your comment!
